# ImportError: No module named seaborn (using interactive mode)

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to use seaborn to generate some plots and am having issues with python not being able to detect the Seaborn module. Most of the answers I have found online relate specifically to Anaconda, which I have installed on my system, however for this project I am NOT running Anaconda but am just calling a python script from the command line.

I installed Seaborn using `pip install seaborn` in my terminal.  However, when I start python in interactive mode and type `import seaborn as sns` I still get an error reading
`ImportError: No module named seaborn` This behavior persists even after rebooting my computer (others have said this fixed their problem)

When i ask `which python` in the terminal i get `/usr/bin/python`

I'm kind of at a loss as to figure out where to go from here.  Other modules I have installed with pip (such as numpy or matplotlib) load in without issue.

Comment: and `which pip`?

Comment: Thank you to both, after running `which pip` i noticed its path was `/usr/local/bin/pip` (as opposed to my python `/usr/bin/python/` ... after reading the other article and fixing my paths the install worked